# Read a WAV file and convert it to an array of amplitudes in Swift

Tags: swift, audio, waveform

I have followed a very good tutorial on [udacity](https://www.udacity.com/) to explore the basis of audio applications with **Swift**. I would like to extend its current functionalities, starting with displaying the waveform of the `WAV` file. For that purpose, I would need to retrieve the amplitude versus sample from the `WAV` file. How could I proceed in swift, given that I have a recorded file already?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`AudioToolBox`  meets you need.

You can use `AudioFileService` to get the audio samples from the audio file, such as the `WAV` file,

Then you can get  the amplitude from every sample.

```
 // this is your desired amplitude data
 public internal(set) var packetsX = [Data]()

 public required init(src path: URL) throws {
        Utility.check(error:  AudioFileOpenURL(path as CFURL, .readPermission, 0,  &playbackFile) ,                // set on output to the AudioFileID
                      operation: "AudioFileOpenURL failed")
        
        guard let file = playbackFile else {
            return
        }
        
        var numPacketsToRead: UInt32 = 0
        
        
        GetPropertyValue(val: &numPacketsToRead, file: file, prop: kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataPacketCount)
        
        var asbdFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
        GetPropertyValue(val: &asbdFormat, file: file, prop: kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat)
        
        dataFormatD = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &asbdFormat)
        /// At this point we should definitely have a data format
        var bytesRead: UInt32 = 0
        GetPropertyValue(val: &bytesRead, file: file, prop: kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount)
        
        
        
        
        guard let dataFormat = dataFormatD else {
            return
        }
        
    
        let format = dataFormat.streamDescription.pointee
        let bytesPerPacket = Int(format.mBytesPerPacket)
        
        for i in 0 ..< Int(numPacketsToRead) {
            
            var packetSize = UInt32(bytesPerPacket)
                
            let packetStart = Int64(i * bytesPerPacket)
            let dataPt: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = malloc(MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size * bytesPerPacket)
            AudioFileReadBytes(file, false, packetStart, &packetSize, dataPt)
            let startPt = dataPt.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: bytesPerPacket)
            let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: startPt, count: bytesPerPacket)
            let array = Array(buffer)
            packetsX.append(Data(array))
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

For example , the `WAV` file has channel one 、bit depth of Int16 .

```
// buffer is of two Int8, to express an Int16
let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: startPt, count: bytesPerPacket)
```

more information , you can check [my github repo](https://github.com/BoxDengJZ/AudioJz/tree/master/AudioToolBox/2_parserRM)